# go-restful extract URL pattern path from request

Tags: rest, go, go-restful

I am using a the emicklei/go-restful framework to deal with rest API.
I wish to access the route path from the request. Meaning that when I configure a dummy route like this:

```
    ws := new(restful.WebService)
    ws.Path("/resources/names")
    ws.Route(ws.GET("/{name}").To(getName))
    restful.DefaultContainer.Add(ws)
```

I wish to access the information that the route was "/resources/names/{name}"

I can access the actual URL which is call by calling:

```
    req.Request.URL.Path
```

But this will return the specific URL, not the generic one.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research I finally found that the method req.SelectedRoutePath() will return expected value.